# Manipulate Activities

Tags: android, android-activity

I have 4 Activities A,B,C,D now I have in each activity a button of Back and button Cancel

Now I went on the button back to move to the activity that I have before example if I am on B when I press on back I get to A that I have done that by finish but the problem that I have is when I am on example C and I press cancel I should get to A but dose not work I try to make a new activity but don't work.
how can I make my function Cancel to take me back to the activity A?

Comment: If you're asking what I think you're asking, this question (or a variant of it)has been asked [many](http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=android+activity+stack#sclient=psy&hl=en&q=android%20activity%20stack%20site%3Astackoverflow.com&aq=&aqi=&aql=&oq=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=f83efc677861d9f9&pf=p&pdl=3000) times already on stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

Just use `onActivityResult()` in middle activity, and while finishing C just add the line

```
setResult(5)
```

in the middle Activity B in `onActivityResult`

just check in resultcode=5 finish it.

[check this link](https://sites.google.com/site/cganapathi/home/android)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Intent with flag `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` in `startActivity`.
So if you have A B C after launching A activity B and C will be closed.

For example on Activity C in cancel button click listener:

```
Intent cancelIntent = new Intent(this, A.class);
cancelIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

startActivity(cncelIntent);
```

Comment: its working for me but if i went to get back to activity A with the same intent like that i will still keep the information of A information